# Prove that $f$ is continuous at $(0, y_0)$ where f is defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$ as follows:

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

Prove that $f$ is continuous at $(0, y_0)$ where $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$ as follows:

$$f(x, y) =
\begin{cases} (1+xy)^{1/x} &\mbox{if } x \neq 0 \\
e^y & \mbox{if } x = 0 \end{cases}$$

**Attempt:**

My approach was to show that this function is a composition of continuous functions. In particular the functions:  $$g(x) = (1+x)$$
$$h(x) = xc \text{ (where $c$ is a constant)}$$
$$n(x) = c^{\frac{1}{x}} $$

Now I have successfully shown that $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are continuous at my point, but I am having problems with $n(x)$ and $e^y$. I think $e^y$ is constant at this point and as such I could just let $\delta = \epsilon$. But $n(x)$ definitely has me confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the well-known limit $\lim_{x \to 0} (1+kx)^{\frac 1x} = e^k$. Hence we have:

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,y_0)} f(x) = \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,y_0)} (1+xy)^{\frac 1x} = \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,y_0)} e^y = e^{y_0} = f(0,y_0)$$

Hence the function is continuous at $(0,y_0)$.

Comment: Out of curiosity, would I have been able to do it the way I suggested? Also I acknowledge it being true, but where could I find a quick proof of  $\lim_{x \to 0} (1+kx)^{\frac 1x} = e^k$?

Comment: You composition is wrong. I guess something like $g(x,y) = (1+xy,x)$ and $n(x,y) = x^{\frac 1y}$ would be the right one. The problem is with the second one, as it's not defined at many points, let alone contious on the whole plane.

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to show that $lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,y_0), y\neq 0}f(x,y)=f(0,y_0)$.

$f(x,y)=e^{{ln(1+xy)}\over x}$ if $x\neq 0$, $lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,y_0})e^{{ln(1+xy)}\over x}$

$lim_{x\rightarrow 0}e^{{ln(1+xy_0)}\over x}=e^{y_0}$

since $lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{{ln(1+xy_0)}\over x}$ is the derivative of $ln(1+xy_0)$ at $0$.